# How to split a a string data into the same column / single column - without affecting the dataset itself (Python Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, data-analysis

The data set I'm working on has got a column with zipcodes in it. Some entries only have one zipcode, some have 2, 5, or 10+ zipcodes. Like this:

| Zipcode(s) |
| --- |
| 1245 |
| 5863, 5682, 1995 |
| 6978, 1123, 5659, 34554 |
| 4539, 6453 |

I want to do some simple analysis -- apply a value_counts() on the column to see what zipcodes are the most popular. But I can't properly do it since most cells have multiple zipcodes on them. That's also the reason why I want a way where it won't affect the dataset itself, just that specific instance where all zipcodes are split and are in one column.

I've tried splitting them into multiple columns with `.str.split(',',n=20, expand=True)` but that's not really what I'm looking for. I want them all split into a single column.

Comment: df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.zipcodes.str.split(r' *, *', regex=True).tolist()).stack().droplevel(0)
And then try value counts, print(df2.value_counts())

Comment: @Thangaselvi tried it, But got this error: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: Could you please help with the input you tried as you got this error. may be try this: pd.DataFrame(df.zipcodes.str.split(r' *, *', regex=True).tolist()).stack().astype(float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [pandas.DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) is what you're looking for.
With this, you take all values from lists (which you created with the `split` function) to a new row.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Zipcodes":["8000", "2000, 2002, 3003", "8000, 2002", "3004, 2004, 3003"]
})

df

(
    df.Zipcodes
    .str.replace(" ", "") # optional, if you don't need this then 
    .str.split(",")       # use ", " instead of ","
    .explode()
    .value_counts()
)
```

**Output:**

```
8000    2
2002    2
3003    2
2000    1
3004    1
2004    1
```

Comment: Hi, it worked! I think? If you don't mind me asking. Do you have any idea why are the index axis repeating instead of creating a new ones for splited/exploded values? The length of the series is definitely longer than original, but it's with repeated index? https://imgur.com/a/35MRXVk

Comment: Yes, it's also written in the docs `Transform each element of a list-like to a row, replicating index values`. Simply use `.reset_index(drop=True)`, if you want to get unique indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this python snippet below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Zipcode(s)" : ["1245", "5863, 5682, 1995", "6978, 1123, 5659, 34554", "4539, 6453"]
})
df["Zipcode(s)"] = df["Zipcode(s)"].map(lambda zcode: zcode.split(", "))
zipcodes = sum(df["Zipcode(s)"].to_list(), [])
#create dummy(empty) dataframe
dummydf = pd.DataFrame({"Zipcode(s)" : zipcodes})
print(dummydf["Zipcode(s)"].value_counts())
```

Output:

```
1245     1
5863     1
5682     1
1995     1
6978     1
1123     1
5659     1
34554    1
4539     1
6453     1
Name: Zipcode(s), dtype: int64
```